# Basic React Native + TypeScript + redux-forms

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, redux-form

I'm just getting started with React Native and TypeScript and I'm trying to add a basic form to my app. I'm a complete noob with this so bear with me. I can get the form to appear but I'm not really sure what I need to put instead of the question marks in the code below to get it to type check correctly:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import { Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native'
import Styles from './Styles'

function renderInput(input: ?): TextInput {
  return <TextInput style={Styles.input} ? />
}

const MyForm = reduxForm({ form: 'my_form' })( props => {
  const { handleSubmit } = props
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Bla</Text>
      <Field name="name" component={renderInput} type="text" />
      </View>  
  )
})

export default HopIngredientForm
```

Definitely bonus points if someone could show me how to instead use a `TextInput` (custom component?) with my own styles without having to define a separate function.

Thanks :)

Comment: `input`? or `Styles.input`? I don't see you're using any `input`

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? input is just the name of the function parameter (probably not a very good one?).

Comment: do u want to use this `input` as prop to `TextInput`?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still at a level where I don't know the answer to that. The only thing I'm trying to achieve right now is a redux-form TextField styled with Styles.input. That's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got you correctly, change the method `renderInput` to this:

```
function renderInput(input: string): JSX.Element {
  return <TextInput style={Styles.input}>{input}</TextInput>
}
```

Comment: It turns out that input is actually an object and the values should be set with initialValues (https://redux-form.com/7.2.2/examples/initializefromstate/) but this  works now. Thanks